# Calculating Upside Potential

Tags: finance

I have a story problem in my finance class. I can't figure out how to determine if my math is correct or not. The problem is:

> You purchase stock for 0.015 (one and a half cent) per share. You
>   purchased 7,500 shares. Several decades later you sell the stock for
>   $1.00 per share. How much money do you have?

I keep coming up with `$746,250.00` and `$7,462,500.00`. I'm not sure which, if either is correct. It seems like there should be a formula for this kind of thing. However, I can't seem to find it. Am I going about this correctly?

THank you!

Comment: Check your arithmetic. How can you have more that \$ 7500?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cost of purchase = Price per share $\times$ Number of shares $= \$0.015 \times 7500 = \$112.5$

Earning from selling = Price per share $\times$ Number of shares $= \$1 \times 7500 = \$7500.$

Net profit $= \$7500 - \$112.5 = \$7487.5$

Comment: $7500-112.50$ is $7387.50$, not $7487.50$